# ruby: Rock Scissors Paper program. How to make algorithm function properly?

Tags: ruby

I'm creating a rock, scissors, paper program for my first program with ruby.

I'm thinking of using a hash called `@wins` to determine if a certain combination wins. If both hands are the same, the result is a `Draw!`. Otherwise, the result is `Lose!`.

I'm struggling to implement the algorithm to judge the results. How do I check if a given combination exists within the `@wins` hash to judge wether it's a win or now?

```
class Hand
    attr_accessor :shape
    @@shapes = [:rock, :scissors, :paper]
    def generate
        @shape = @@shapes[rand(3)]
    end
end

class Game
    @wins = {rock: :scissors, scissors: :paper, paper: :rock}
    def judge(p1, p2)
        'Win!'  if (a way to see if a given combination exists within a @wins hash)         # Not working
        'Draw!' if p1 == p2 # Not working
        else 'Lose!'
    end
end

player_hand = Hand.new
player_hand.shape = ARGV.join.to_sym
puts player_hand.shape # Debug

computer_hand = Hand.new
computer_hand.shape = computer_hand.generate
puts computer_hand.shape # Debug

game = Game.new
puts game.judge(player_hand.shape, computer_hand.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def judge(p1, p2)
  case
    when @wins[p1] == p2 then "Win"
    when @wins[p2] == p1 then "Lose"
    else "Draw"
  end
end
```

Comment: 13:in `judge': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from 29:in `<main>'`

Comment: Ah, right. `@wins =...` should be in the `initialize` method; the way you have it now, it's setting it on the class, and `judge` can't see it. Even better (much better), make it a constant (`WINS = ...`), in which case it stays right where it is (no `initialize`).